# SQL tuning: division between the sum of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(COL1) / SUM(COL2) FROM table_name
```

My questions:

1. Error handling. If SUM(COL2) is 0, what will return for most
   database implementations? How can I return 0 in this case?
2. Performance tuning. Is it **usually** guaranteed that these 2 SUM()
   will be computed in a single loop instead of going through all the
   records to compute SUM(COL1) then going through everything again to
   compute SUM(COL2)? If it's not guaranteed, how to improve the
   performance such that this division can be done in a single loop by the database engine?

**You can answer this question based on the database engine you are familiar with.**

---

*(I have already got lots of excellent answers to Question 1, but it seems that nobody knows the answer to Question 2.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (column1 INT, column2 INT)

INSERT INTO @Table 
VALUES
(0, 0)

SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Column2) > 0 
    THEN
        SUM(column1) / SUM(column2) 
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Sum Division]
FROM @Table
```

Will give a 0 value if column2's sum is not greater than 0 (includes nulls).

**EDIT**

This assumes that you won't have negative values in column2.  If negative values are possible, you would want to use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Column2) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(Column2) <> 0 
    THEN
        SUM(column1) / SUM(column2) 
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Sum Division]
FROM @Table
```

This will do the calculations for all non 0 **NUMBERS**.  But, for **0** or **NULL** values, it will just return 0.

Comment: since no one answered my question 2, I will accept this answer as it is more independent from specific database engine and provides better readability. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL Server solution for Question 1.

```
SELECT COALESCE((SUM(COL1) / NULLIF(SUM(COL2),0)),0) FROM table_name
```

I don't know the answer to question 2, however I can say that I've never seen any other alternative to the way you've written the query being chosen over this way, and I find it safe to assume that this is the most efficient way the query can be written.

Comment: `NULLIF(SUM(COL2),0))` in the denominator?

Comment: @vkp Yes, if the denominator is zero, you will get a `division by zero` error, so we change zero to NULL prior to doing the division.   If the numerator is zero, we will correctly get zero with no error, so no need to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

In case MySQL It's answer on question 1:

```
select CASE WHEN IFNULL(sum(COL2),0) <> 0 THEN (IFNULL(sum(COL1),0) / sum(COL2) ) ELSE 0 END  from table_name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the ternary operator too. Is easy to understand by other coders and simply to read. And there is support on almost every db engine.

SELECT IF( SUM(COL2) = 0, SUM(COL1) / SUM(COL2), -1) FROM table_name